# Run length decoder in C#

Tags: c#, run-length-encoding

Is it possible that anyone around here might have a run-length DECODER in C#? I'm in real need of said code. Thanks.

```
using System;
class RLDEC
{
static void Main()
{
   int t = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

   for (int k = 0; k < t; k++)
    {
       string s = Console.ReadLine();
       s = runLengthDecoder(s);
       Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

}

   static string runLengthDecoder(string s)
   {
      string d = ""; // decoded string
      int cv; // current value

      for(int k = 0; k < s.Length; k++)
       {
          cv = Convert.ToInt32(s[k]) - 48;

          if (k + 1 < s.Length && cv != 1 && cv >= 2 && cv <= 9)
           {
             for(int v = 0; v < cv; v++)
               d += s[k+1];
           }

          if (cv == 1)
          {
             int z = k + 1;
             while(k < s.Length && z < s.Length && Convert.ToInt32(s[z]) - 48 != 1)
              {
                d += s[z];
                z++;
                k++;
              }
             k++;
          }
       }
      return d;
   }
}
```

Comment: It would be beneficial to include details on how far you've got already.

Comment: No, it's not homework. I'm preparing myself for a test by working on certain types of code.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to solve this without the specification for your encoding, but in this code

```
     if (k + 1 < s.Length && cv != 1 && cv >= 2 && cv <= 9)
       {
         for(int v = 0; v < cv; v++)
           d += s[k+1];
       }
```

I would expect k to be incremented before leaving the if block.

Also, I would expect that the next `if (cv==1)` is an `else if` instead.

In that `cv==1` block, I think you should just process then next character and let the outer for loop do its work.

I also don't understand how that block could work at all